# How to move Success, Error messages position?

Tags: magento2, layout, messages, global-messages

How to move **Add to cart** `success` and `error` message above **Add to cart button** and not at the **top** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it by the layout. I didn't test it but it should work.

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` in your theme and add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.messages" destination="product.info.form.content" before="product.info.addtocart" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: it's not working for me M 2.3.4, the message has gone after that

Answer (score 1):

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="page.messages" destination="product.info.form.content" as="page.messages" after="addtocart"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: it's not working for me M 2.3.4, the message has gone after that