# Display message from message manager above specific block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, global-messages

I have redirection from controller to CMS page with custom message defined using **messageManager**.

It show up the message before my CMS page content begins (below header part).
but i want to display that message above specific block of that CMS page.

This is how my CMS page is

```
/*** HTML content ***/
{{block name="custom-form" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::custom_form/index.phtml"}}
```

How can we do it?

I have referred [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220998/how-to-move-success-error-messages-position) which suggests to make change in layout file, which won't be useful in my case.

Can **Layout Update XML** of **Design** section of CMS page be useful in this case? I wrote below line in that field but no effect.

`<move element="page.messages" destination="custom-form"  />`

Or is there any way to move message inside **custom_form/index.phtml** ?